# get objects from NSMutable array with condition objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I want to get some objects from array contains objects where one of objects property satisfy the condition

Like in c#

example :

```
NSMutablearray * coursesinfo ;
```

this array contain more than 30 courses

course is object on of its property is finalgrade

i want to get all courses `where final grade < 100`

can i do this in objective -c like c# ? and how?

Comment: Just use the for each loop and check the condition? What is the problem here?

Comment: i asked if there another solution like where statement in C#

Comment: Read the spec.  There are several versions of `indexOfObjectPassingTest`, along with several different sorting options.

Comment: Why some many downvotes? That's a good question, objective-c looks quite lame after using c# LINQ and lambda expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the where statement is like using a predicate in cocoa/cocoa touch.  here is an example, where I have an array of image file names from a directory and I am looking for the base file name.  The indexesOfObjectsWithOptions: method returns a set of Indices that pass the specific test.  NSEnumerationConcurrent utilizes a concurrent queue to take advantage of multiple cores, if present.

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet=[allImageURLs indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    BOOL match=NO;
    NSRange twoXRange=[((NSURL *)obj).absoluteString rangeOfString:@"@2x"];
    NSRange iPhoneRange=[((NSURL *)obj).absoluteString rangeOfString:@"~ipad"];
    if (twoXRange.location==NSNotFound && iPhoneRange.location==NSNotFound) {
        match=YES;
    }
    return  match;
}];

self.imageURLs=[allImageURLs objectsAtIndexes: indexSet];
```

for your particular case I would do the following:

```
NSIndexSet *theSet=[coursesinfo indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent passingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    BOOL match=NO;

    if( obj.finalGrade<100 ){
       match=YES;
    }
    return match;
}];

NSArray *courses=[coursesinfo objectsAtIndexes: theSet];
```

Good luck!

t

Answer (score 0):

The closest is use `- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` function of NSArray.

Link to [NSPredicate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPredicate).